# LayoutInflater returns null view Android

Tags: java, android

I have a `RecyclerView` with a custom view being used as the holder. Whenever the `ViewHolder` class is constructed, it calls the `findViewById` method on the view being passed through, but I get a `NullPointerException`. I'm figuring it's a problem with the inflater.

Here's my code:

```java
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.boxview_layout, parent, true);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            JSONObject pos = jsonList.getJSONObject(position);
            holder.setText(pos.getString("text"));
            holder.setTitle(pos.getString("title"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jsonList.length();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView text;
        private View view;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.title = view.findViewById(R.id.titleBox);
            this.text = view.findViewById(R.id.textBox);
            this.view = v;
        }

        public View getCustomView() {
            return view;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

And here's the view being inflated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleBox"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:text="Filler title"
        custom:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        custom:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBox"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Filler text"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        custom:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        custom:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleBox" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `this.title = view.findViewById(R.id.titleBox);` – If I'm following your description correctly, it's because you're calling `findViewById()` on your `private View view;` field before you've assigned it in the `this.view = v;` line at the end.

Comment: @MikeM. wow, I can't believe I missed something that simple. Sometimes it takes a fresh pair of eyes :D